# why does new File("") not provide an existing directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse+Java and trying to create files under my current project. I have used `new File("")` and do not understand its behaviour.

```
File dir = new File("");
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()+" | "+dir.isDirectory()+" | "+dir.exists());
String absolutePathname = dir.getAbsolutePath();
dir = new File(absolutePathname);
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()+" | "+dir.isDirectory()+" | "+dir.exists());
```

results in:

```
D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem | false | false
D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem | true | true
```

Why can I have two files which have the same absolute pathname one of which exists and one of which does not?

I am using Java 1.6 and Eclipse Helios

Comment: "I am using Eclipse+Java and trying to create files under my current project. .."  That is where you have already gone wrong.  Put them in a sub-directory of user.home instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File dir = new File("");
means a file with name "empty string" and
naturally this file doesn't exist and it is not a directory.
To refer current directory, use File dir = new File(".");
look at this code:

```
File dir = new File("");
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()+" | "+dir.isDirectory()+" | "+dir.exists());
System.out.println("file name is: |" + dir.getName() + "|");
String absolutePathname = dir.getAbsolutePath();
dir = new File(absolutePathname);**
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()+" | "+dir.isDirectory()+" | "+dir.exists());
System.out.println("file name is: |" + dir.getName() + "|");
```

notice a different file name:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin | false | false
file name is: ||
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin | true | true
file name is: |bin|
```

Answer (score 3):

Because, you're asking the following questions:

1. If I get the full path of "", what is it? `D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem`
2. Is "" a real directory? `No.`
3. Does "" exist in some way? `No.`
4. If I get the full path of "D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem", what is it? `D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem`
5. Is "D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem" a real directory? `Yes.`
6. Does "D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem" exist in some way? `Yes.`

The reason #1 works is because any relative path (i.e., a path that doesn't start with `/` or a drive) can be made absolute by combining it with the current directory. So:

`"D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem" + "" == "D:\workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-compchem"`